# What does the remainder operation (x % y) do when x < y?

Tags: c

This program correctly prints whether a number is even or odd ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int n;
    printf("Please enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if(n % 2 == 0)
        printf("%d is even", n);
    else
        printf("%d is odd",n);

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand how `n % 2` can give a meaningful result when `n` is less than two.  `%` is the remainder operation, right?  If `n` is less than two, how can you divide it by two at all?

Comment: What do you think happens if the input value is less than 2?

Comment: `n%2` returns the remainder of the division by two... so an even number is always divisible by two (i.e. remainder 0) whilst dividing an odd number always leaves a remainder of 1.

Comment: Please explain how you understand `3 % 2` but not `1 % 2`.

Comment: Do you know what does `%` means in C programming languages ?

Comment: if user put the value of n=0 or n=1. Then how that program will work?

Comment: I think this is actually a sensible, although poorly expressed, question, so I have taken the liberty of revising it to make it clearer what you are confused about.

Comment: The question seems to be "What is division?"

Comment: @MattMcNabb "How is integer division defined in this specific corner case that wasn't covered in the OP's grade-school math classes and which (to someone who doesn't know it *is* defined by the laws of arithmetic) might vary from language to language or CPU to CPU" is an on-topic question.

Comment: Given `(x % y)` if `x < y` then `(x % y) = x`. You shouldn't confuse `%` with `/` they are two completely different operations. So,  `x % y` does not mean `x divided by y`

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c/

Comment: @Adjit: Untrue (for negative numbers case), e.g. `-3 % 2` results into `-1`. According to C standard (C11 §6.5.5/6) there is "truncation towards zero", so `-3 / 2` results into `-1`, then `-1*2 + r = -3`, thus `r = -3 + 2 = -1` (according to `(a/b)*b + a%b = a` equation).

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski very true, probably should've specified when `x & y >= 0`

Comment: @Adjit Any operation to find `/` also finds `%` in the same process. (CPUs use a single instruction to generate both).  `x % y` is defined as `x - (x / y) * y`.   Both are "division", just one of them says "take the quotient and discard the remainder" and the other says "take the remainder and discard the quotient"

Comment: Formally: find the unique solution to `x = Q * y + R` where if Q is negative then `Q < R` and `R <= 0`, or otherwise, `0 <= R` and `R < Q`.  Then `x/y` is defined as `Q`, and `x%y` is defined as `R`.

Comment: @Adjit: I have made a mistake in calculations, now it should be correct. The whole my point was to show that your rule fails for negative numbers, at least using C standard semantics.

Comment: @MattMcNabb was talking about this more from a mathematical standpoint. (1 mod 2). Yes you are right that modulo is a variation of division but the two are not the same thing.

Comment: In that code we are giving the condition n%2==0. I am asking that if value of n would be 0 or 1, that is less than two. How that program will find the number is even or odd. It is bit confusing for me.

Comment: @AsifNaeem work out `n / 2` and then apply the equation `n - (n / 2) * 2` . that gives you `n % 2` .

Comment: @Adjit "integer division" generates two outputs, called Quotient and Remainder.  the quotient and the remainder are different, but both are an output of "division".

Comment: it is like 1%2 where quotient will be .5 and reminder will be 0. Same on 2%2. Quotient will be 1 and reminder will be 0. 3%2. Quotient will be 1 and reminder will be 1. I am clear now. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @MattMcNabb right. I guess I've always found it easier to just think of them as different entities stemming from the same operation

Comment: @AsifNaeem in integer division, the quotient is always an integer. [See this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c/) if you are unsure about that

Comment: @AsifNaeem read to your hearts content : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thank you for suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

> I am unable to understand the logic of n%2==0. If user input a value less than 2. Then how it give us correct answer?

The operator `%` performs the modulus (or remainder) operation. The remainder of dividing a number by 2 (when that number is less than 2) is the number itself (with the quotient being 0). For example, one divided by two has a quotient of 0 and a remainder of 1 so 1%2 = 1.

Comment: How you are proving that 1%2=1?

Comment: @AsifNaeem I'm not proving it, I'm asserting it. To prove it is grade school math; how many times does to 2 go into 1? 0. And 0*2 is 0, and 1 - 0 is 1. Therefor, the remainder of 1/2 is 1. QED.